# Get list of all table names from spring SimpleJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

Is there a way to obtain the list of all table names in the database using Spring's SimpleJdbcTemplate?

The database being queried is Oracle if that helps in any way. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring has a [`DatabaseMetaDataCallback`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/DatabaseMetaDataCallback.html) object that can take care of some of the boiler plate aspects of the solution that duffymo has linked to.  You can then pass that object when calling [`JDBCUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/JdbcUtils.html#extractDatabaseMetaData%28javax.sql.DataSource,%20org.springframework.jdbc.support.DatabaseMetaDataCallback%29).

An example of making the same call you're trying to make with those classes can be found [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=5248&postcount=5).

Sample code from that link:

Class:

```
class GetTableNames implements DatabaseMetaDataCallback {

        public Object processMetaData(DatabaseMetaData dbmd) throws SQLException {
            ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(dbmd.getUserName(), null, null, new String[]{"TABLE"});
            ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
            while (rs.next()) {
                l.add(rs.getString(3));
            }
            return l;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
GetTableNames getTableNames = new GetTableNames();
try {
    Object o = JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(dataSource, getTableNames);
    System.out.println(o);
} catch (MetaDataAccessException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You're always free to get java.sql.DatabaseMetaData using the Connection.  There aren't any methods in SimpleJdbcTemplate to help you, but frankly there's no need.

```
DatabaseMetaData md = c.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
}
```

Comment: It's possible that the spring aspect is important due to transaction manager interactions or something.

Comment: I wouldn't think transactions are needed for a read-only operation like this.  The only problem could be if someone changes the schema while you're performing the operation in such a way that the result is invalidated.  If that can happen, you've got far bigger issues.

Comment: That link is currently redirecting to a phising site

Comment: What is it about low rep folks that they go looking for six year old answers to comment on?

Answer (score 1):

Query the USER_TABLES view and you will get them.

poke around in sqlplus, of course, to see the shape first.

Comment: In my experience, the application's "tables" are often synonyms to tables in another schema, so you may have to query ALL_TABLES also.